# MySQL connection help - root user HAS privileges, but is being denied access?

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I've been trying to figure this out for a solid 24 hours.

I'm with GoDaddy for hosting. I have installed MySQL Server and Workbench. I've successfully created my root user with a password on my local server.

I'm trying to send form data using post method to a database I've successfully created with Workbench.

When submitting the form, I keep getting the error: ERROR: Could not connect. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I've tried creating a new user and granting all privileges to that new user as well, but it still doesn't work. Nothing is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most (if not all) hosters will not allow you to connect to your database form any other machine than their own.  Ex. I have a site on 1and1, I can only connect to the database from my web server, which also reside on 1and1.  Nothing from home is allowed.  Is that the case here?

Comment: quite possible. i'll have to contact godaddy and see if they know.